# How to co_await GetFilesAsync in latest cppwinrt?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, c++-winrt

With the help of cppwinrt people I previously had managed to enumerate files in a StorageFolder; at the time I was missing a needed #include. Worked fine until I rebuilt the app using as a starting point the BlankApp now provided by Visual Studio 15.9.0 Preview 3 as a template C++/WinRT app. Now that same code produces a link error that I can't get past. Let me quote the offending line: this is part of a class I call ResourceManager; it contains a reference to a folder defined this way:

```cpp
IVectorView<StorageFile> m_activity_files = nullptr;
```

Then the class has a method, declared as

```cpp
IAsyncAction LoadActivities();
```

which co_awaits a call to get the appropriate StorageFolder as m_activities_folder and once that is done, tries to enumerate the folder contents:

```cpp
m_activity_files = co_await m_activities_folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery::DefaultQuery);
```

And that is where the trouble lies. What used to work fine now produces the following link error:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVectorView<struct winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile> > __thiscall winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Storage_Search_IStorageFolderQueryOperations<struct winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFolder>::GetFilesAsync(enum winrt::Windows::Storage::Search::CommonFileQuery const &)const " (?GetFilesAsync@?$consume_Windows_Storage_Search_IStorageFolderQueryOperations@UStorageFolder@Storage@Windows@winrt@@@impl@winrt@@QBE?AU?$IAsyncOperation@U?$IVectorView@UStorageFile@Storage@Windows@winrt@@@Collections@Foundation@Windows@winrt@@@Foundation@Windows@3@ABW4CommonFileQuery@Search@Storage@63@@Z) referenced in function "public: struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction __thiscall AppEngine::ResourceManager::LoadActivities$_ResumeCoro$2(void)" (?LoadActivities$_ResumeCoro$2@ResourceManager@AppEngine@@QAE?AUIAsyncAction@Foundation@Windows@winrt@@XZ)
```

(Followed by path to the object file)   The includes and namespaces are the same as before, and it doesn't seem to matter whether or not I use fully-qualified names in the arguments.

```cpp
#include "winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Search.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.UI.Core.h"
#include "pch.h"
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::Storage;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Provider;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Search;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
```

But I cannot figure out what the trouble is. It appears that something has changed in the latest revisions to C++/WinRT and SDK 10.0.17666.0. What I would really love to see is (for every method, really) a few lines of sample code that demonstrate the use of C++/WinRT, but just solving this would be enough for now!

[UPDATE] Is it significant that the link error refers to IAsyncOperation when this call is in a method with return type IAsyncAction?

[Update 2] Using the PhotoEditor sample app as a model I wondered if perhaps it would be better to create a FileQuery and run the GetFilesAsync on that. So:

```cpp
QueryOptions options{};
        options.FolderDepth(FolderDepth::Shallow);
        options.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".act");
        auto result = m_activities_folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);
auto activityFiles = co_await result.GetFilesAsync();
```

Of course Windows.Storage.Search is already #included, and its namespace declared as above. But now I get an additional link error on the QueryOptions:

```cpp
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall winrt::Windows::Storage::Search::QueryOptions::QueryOptions(void)" (??0QueryOptions@Search@Storage@Windows@winrt@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: struct winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction __thiscall AppEngine::ResourceManager::LoadActivities$_ResumeCoro$2(void)" (?LoadActivities$_ResumeCoro$2@ResourceManager@AppEngine@@QAE?AUIAsyncAction@Foundation@Windows@winrt@@XZ)
```

Could there be some basic issue with the BlankApp project settings?

Comment: I appreciate the reply, Hans. But if I target the next down available version, 17133, Canvas doesn't work. If I set the target to 17166 and the minimum to 17133 then there's a static assertion error in the main .h file (never have understood how the program can target a version unless that is also the minimum version). Maybe I have to wait for a fix.

Comment: Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/threading-async/asynchronous-programming-universal-windows-platform-apps#asynchronous-patterns-in-uwp-with-cwinrt).

Comment: Thanks, CoCalceDew, but while the doc has some useful information it still doesn't get me to an explanation of why the call to GetFilesAsync used to build and no longer does. Still stumped here.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd consider using a different name than `ResourceManager` because it's also Windows type you might want to use for managing resources (like localized strings or images with multiple resolutions for different scale factors).

Comment: Thanks Peter. My own ResourceManager is in a separate namespace, but still it would probably best to make that more unique.

Comment: Someone at MS has suggested that I target the latest release SDK, 17763. I downloaded that SDK and targeted it  but that produces over a thousand build errors at the system level, so I've gone back to targeting 17666. The computer is running 18262. Not looking good at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's what I did, and it worked. First, I gave up use of CommonFileQuery. Instead of

```
m_activity_files = co_await m_activities_folder.GetFilesAsync(winrt::Windows::Storage::Search::CommonFileQuery::DefaultQuery);
```

I instead simply used

```
m_activity_files = co_await activitiesFolder.GetFilesAsync();
```

And that built. Then I found that using the StorageFolder's method to get an internal folder was crashing, so I now get the desired folder by using its path:

```
std::wstring path{ Windows::ApplicationModel::Package::Current().InstalledLocation().Path() + L"\\Assets\\Activities" };
Windows::Storage::StorageFolder activitiesFolder{ co_await Windows::Storage::StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync(path) };
```

And that works! The process of getting to success seemed almost random, but I'm OK as long as it keeps working. I do wonder about why I cannot target the latest release SDK, though, since its version is later than the 17666 I'm targeting right now. Thanks to all who made suggestions.

Comment: I should add that I have now retargeted to 17763 by creating a new template and adding back the files from this project - simply using the retargeting command didn't quite do the job. Good news is that now the GetFolderAsync() and GetFilesAsync() work as they should, with the sole exception that I can't use the CommonFileQuery argument in the latter, which could be my fault, but otherwise the calls now work fine. The newer system is apparently needed.